# How to take a normal coordinate to make the second fundamental form diagonal?

Tags: riemannian-geometry

I'm reading Escobar's The Yamabe Problem On Manifolds With Boundary.

He says

> Let $(y_{1},\cdots,y_{n})$  be normal coordinates around $0\in \partial M$,such that $\eta(0)=-\frac{\partial}{\partial y_{n}}$,and second fundamental form of $\partial M$ at 0  has a diagonal form.

Here $M$ is a Riemannian manifolds with boundary and $0$ is a nonumbilic point on $\partial M$.$\eta$ represents the outward normal.

I wonder how can we take such a normal coordinates.

In fact if we take a normal coordinates at $0$,which satisfies $g_{ij}(0)=\delta_{ij},\Gamma_{ij}^{k}(0)=0.$

Then we compute
$$h_{ij}(0)=g(\nabla_{\partial y^{i}}\partial y^{n},\partial_{y^{j}})=\Gamma_{in}^{k}g_{kj}=0.$$

This means its second fundamental form is 0.But this seems strange to me.

Is this true?Any help will be thanked.

Comment: What is $\eta$?

Comment: @ArcticChar $\eta$ represents the outward normal,I edited it.